# How to display __EFMigrationsHistory in console?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, migration

I'm using EF Core to apply migration on a db. I have a MainContext and I'm using in my program:

```
using MainContext ctxMain = new();
Console.WriteLine("--> Creating  database...");
ctxMain.Database.Migrate();
Console.WriteLine("--> Done creating database!");
```

I'm trying to show in the console the migrationhistory for every file it migrates.

If I use in the console the dotnet ef database update --context MainContext
it shows the info
[console migration info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/761YN.png)
But if I run directly from the program, it doesn't show, and I cant use a Console.WriteLine inside the Migration method, since it's part of the EntityFrameworkCore.
[no console migration info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3LgS.png)

How can I show that info when using

```
ctxMain.Database.Migrate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to change LogLevel in appsettings.json (or specyfic for environment if you have more of them), or you can do it via code, just for migration. "Microsoft" part is responsible for that.

```
"Logging": {
   "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
   }
}
```

After that you should see something like this in output (I had no migrations pending so it's empty)

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='180']
SELECT migrationid, productversion
FROM __efmigrationshistory
ORDER BY migrationid;
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations: Information: No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
```

Comment: My appsettings only have the ConnectionStrings atributte. How can i do it via code?

Comment: Just paste that part into appsettings before last '}' Changing it via code is more tricky, google for changing log level in net core at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, ive tried to add it on appsettings but it didnt work.. ill go google for changing log level.